# Search for file names of a certain length on Unix

Tags: unix, shell, search

How do I search for all files of a certain length in a directory, in UNIX? For example, how do I search for all files whose names are of length 5 in the directory /blah?

I've looked all over and I can't find it at all.

Answer (score 10):

Anything wrong with

```
ls /blah/?????
```

As in

```
$ ls blah/*
blah/apple  blah/bananas  blah/pears  blah/pie

$ ls blah/?????
blah/apple  blah/pears
```

Comment: +1 `?` is an underrated wildcard.

Answer (score 5):

```
find /blah -maxdepth 1 -iname '?????' -xtype f
```

Comment: It tells me both maxdepth and iname are bad options.

Comment: What version of find? mine was find from gnu findutils-4.4.0.

Comment: Doesn't need to be `iname` (case insensitive) if all you are matching is wildcards...  Otherwise, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ls | awk '{if (length($1)==10) print $1}'
```

Comment: Unix supported spaces in file names since at least 1980's.